# React Data Grid UI crashes after running npm run build and npm run start

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-data-grid

I am facing an issue with my Next.js app where the React Data Grid table UI crashes after building and deploying with **`npm run build`** and **`npm run start`**. During development (**`npm run dev`**), everything works fine. I'm seeking assistance to identify and resolve this issue.

[While debugging npm run dev](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgV5C.png)

[After deploying with npm run build and npm run start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuhUg.png)

```js
"use client";

import { useMemo, useState } from "react";
import { createPortal } from "react-dom";
import { faker } from "@faker-js/faker";
import "../../styles/globals.css";

import DataGrid, {
  SelectCellFormatter,
  SelectColumn,
  textEditor,
  type Column,
  type SortColumn,
} from "react-data-grid";

const dateFormatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en");
const currencyFormatter = new Intl.NumberFormat("en", {
  style: "currency",
  currency: "eur",
});

interface SummaryRow {
  id: string;
  totalCount: number;
  yesCount: number;
}

interface Row {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  client: string;
  area: string;
  country: string;
  contact: string;
  assignee: string;
  progress: number;
  startTimestamp: number;
  endTimestamp: number;
  budget: number;
  transaction: string;
  account: string;
  version: string;
  available: boolean;
}

function getColumns(direction: any): readonly Column<Row, SummaryRow>[] {
  return [
    SelectColumn,
    {
      key: "id",
      name: "ID",
      frozen: true,
      resizable: false,
      renderSummaryCell() {
        return <strong>Total</strong>;
      },
    },
    {
      key: "title",
      name: "Task",
      frozen: true,
      renderEditCell: textEditor,
      renderSummaryCell({ row }) {
        return `${row.totalCount} records`;
      },
    },
    {
      key: "client",
      name: "Client",
      width: "max-content",
      draggable: true,
      renderEditCell: textEditor,
    },
    {
      key: "area",
      name: "Area",
      renderEditCell: textEditor,
    },
    {
      key: "contact",
      name: "Contact",
      renderEditCell: textEditor,
    },
    {
      key: "assignee",
      name: "Assignee",
      renderEditCell: textEditor,
    },
    {
      key: "progress",
      name: "Completion",
      renderCell(props) {
        const value = props.row.progress;
        return (
          <>
            <progress max={100} value={value} style={{ inlineSize: 50 }} />{" "}
            {Math.round(value)}%
          </>
        );
      },
      renderEditCell({ row, onRowChange, onClose }) {
        return createPortal(
          <div
            dir={direction}
            className={"dialogContainerClassname"}
            onKeyDown={(event) => {
              if (event.key === "Escape") {
                onClose();
              }
            }}
          >
            <dialog open>
              <input
                autoFocus
                type="range"
                min="0"
                max="100"
                value={row.progress}
                onChange={(e) =>
                  onRowChange({ ...row, progress: e.target.valueAsNumber })
                }
              />
              <menu>
                <button type="button" onClick={() => onClose()}>
                  Cancel
                </button>
                <button type="button" onClick={() => onClose(true)}>
                  Save
                </button>
              </menu>
            </dialog>
          </div>,
          document.body
        );
      },
      editorOptions: {
        displayCellContent: true,
      },
    },
    {
      key: "startTimestamp",
      name: "Start date",
      renderCell(props) {
        return dateFormatter.format(props.row.startTimestamp);
      },
    },
    {
      key: "endTimestamp",
      name: "Deadline",
      renderCell(props) {
        return dateFormatter.format(props.row.endTimestamp);
      },
    },
    {
      key: "budget",
      name: "Budget",
      renderCell(props) {
        return currencyFormatter.format(props.row.budget);
      },
    },
    {
      key: "transaction",
      name: "Transaction type",
    },
    {
      key: "account",
      name: "Account",
    },
    {
      key: "version",
      name: "Version",
      renderEditCell: textEditor,
    },
    {
      key: "available",
      name: "Available",
      renderCell({ row, onRowChange, tabIndex }) {
        return (
          <SelectCellFormatter
            value={row.available}
            onChange={() => {
              onRowChange({ ...row, available: !row.available });
            }}
            tabIndex={tabIndex}
          />
        );
      },
      renderSummaryCell({ row: { yesCount, totalCount } }) {
        return `${Math.floor((100 * yesCount) / totalCount)}% ✔️`;
      },
    },
  ];
}

function rowKeyGetter(row: Row) {
  return row.id;
}

function createRows(): readonly Row[] {
  const now = Date.now();
  const rows: Row[] = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    rows.push({
      id: i,
      title: `Task #${i + 1}`,
      client: faker.company.name(),
      area: faker.person.jobArea(),
      country: faker.location.country(),
      contact: faker.internet.exampleEmail(),
      assignee: faker.person.fullName(),
      progress: Math.random() * 100,
      startTimestamp: now - Math.round(Math.random() * 1e10),
      endTimestamp: now + Math.round(Math.random() * 1e10),
      budget: 500 + Math.random() * 10500,
      transaction: faker.finance.transactionType(),
      account: faker.finance.iban(),
      version: faker.system.semver(),
      available: Math.random() > 0.5,
    });
  }

  return rows;
}

type Comparator = (a: Row, b: Row) => number;

function getComparator(sortColumn: string): Comparator {
  switch (sortColumn) {
    case "assignee":
    case "title":
    case "client":
    case "area":
    case "country":
    case "contact":
    case "transaction":
    case "account":
    case "version":
      return (a, b) => {
        return a[sortColumn].localeCompare(b[sortColumn]);
      };
    case "available":
      return (a, b) => {
        return a[sortColumn] === b[sortColumn] ? 0 : a[sortColumn] ? 1 : -1;
      };
    case "id":
    case "progress":
    case "startTimestamp":
    case "endTimestamp":
    case "budget":
      return (a, b) => {
        return a[sortColumn] - b[sortColumn];
      };
    default:
      throw new Error(`unsupported sortColumn: "${sortColumn}"`);
  }
}

function Home() {
  const [rows, setRows] = useState(createRows);
  const [sortColumns, setSortColumns] = useState<readonly SortColumn[]>([]);
  const [selectedRows, setSelectedRows] = useState(
    (): ReadonlySet<number> => new Set()
  );

  const columns = useMemo(() => getColumns("ltr"), []);

  const summaryRows = useMemo((): readonly SummaryRow[] => {
    return [
      {
        id: "total_0",
        totalCount: rows.length,
        yesCount: rows.filter((r) => r.available).length,
      },
    ];
  }, [rows]);

  const sortedRows = useMemo((): readonly Row[] => {
    if (sortColumns.length === 0) return rows;

    return [...rows].sort((a, b) => {
      for (const sort of sortColumns) {
        const comparator = getComparator(sort.columnKey);
        const compResult = comparator(a, b);
        if (compResult !== 0) {
          return sort.direction === "ASC" ? compResult : -compResult;
        }
      }
      return 0;
    });
  }, [rows, sortColumns]);

  const gridElement = (
    <DataGrid
      rowKeyGetter={rowKeyGetter}
      columns={columns}
      rows={sortedRows}
      defaultColumnOptions={{
        sortable: true,
        resizable: true,
      }}
      selectedRows={selectedRows}
      onSelectedRowsChange={setSelectedRows}
      onRowsChange={setRows}
      sortColumns={sortColumns}
      onSortColumnsChange={setSortColumns}
      topSummaryRows={summaryRows}
      bottomSummaryRows={summaryRows}
      className="fill-grid"
      direction="ltr"
    />
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <div className={"toolbarClassname"}></div>
      {gridElement}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

**What I've Tried:**

- Working fine locally means that when I run **`npm run dev`**
- Mention whether the issue persists only after deployment or also locally.

**Expected Outcome:**

- It should be like how it works locally.

**Next.js Environment:**

- React version: 18
- Next.js version: 14.1.0
- react-data-grid version: 7.0.0-beta.42
- Package manager: npm

Comment: Currently working on a Next.js 14 project using react-data-grid@7.0.0-beta.42 too, but I don't experience any issues. Do you have a repository you can share? Or is there any errors? "It doesn't work" is hard to identify.

Comment: Hi, code included. Please review

Comment: Created a project just now and copied this code from https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid/blob/main/website/demos/CommonFeatures.tsx

Comment: What exactly is not working? what is the error?

Comment: Included images, Please check. If I run npm run dev, the table will be rendered perfectly, If I run npm run build and npm run start, UI crashes

Answer (score 0):

After creating a new project and rendering the code you have provided I identified the issue to be a [hydration error](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error).

This issue occurs because there is a mismatch between the React tree rendered during the first render in the browser (called hydration), and the React tree that was pre-rendered from the server. Specifically this few lines cause the error:

```js
function createRows(): readonly Row[] {
  const now = Date.now();
  const rows: Row[] = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    rows.push({
      id: i,
      title: `Task #${i + 1}`,
      client: faker.company.name(),
      area: faker.person.jobArea(),
      // ....
    });
  }

  return rows;
}
```

To solve this issue, generate the rows with Faker.js on the server and pass it to the `<Home />` component as prop.

```js
import "react-data-grid/lib/styles.css";
```

Furthermore I have noticed that this example does not import the style sheet for the library. You may want to do this too:

Comment: Sorry Fabio, Made the changes hydration error disappeared. But still facing the same issue.

Comment: Seems the UI issue was fixed after avoiding frozen, resizable, and renderEditCell from columns. But I need those features.

Comment: Sure, Let's see.